How to read and write large amounts of data to Cassandra DB?
I have a client application that connects to two or more Cassandra DB servers -- and has to copy some tables from one server to another.
What is the best way to copy big amounts of Cassandra data, especially using Python?

If you are talking to database servers here, then you have little choice.  You'll be using the Cassandra APIs, right?  The database connector will do the copying.

The best way? From one cluster to another?
You'll probably want to use DSBulk for that. Unfortunately, there really isn't a good programatic solution to reading/writing large amounts of data between clusters.
DSBulk, on the other hand, was designed to handle that. In this case, you'll run a dsbulk unload from a cluster/keyspace/table combination out to a file. Then, you'll run a dsbulk load on that file, sending it to the new cluster/keyspace/table. Give the docs a look for details on how to run it.
